# How to get the value of a instance variable in one method to another method in same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One method in my controller is as follows:

```
def new_equipment_matches_wanted
 #..........Big chucnk of code of about 7 to 8 lines and then..
 @receiver
end
```

Now I am defining another method where I want to access the value of this `@receiver` instance variable. And it will have a separate template.

```
def send_receivers_to_admin
 #supposedly I am trying send @receiver values here
end
```

How can I achieve this? Or should I write the same code in the second method also just to access the values in that variable?

Comment: Passing instance variables between methods is a non-problem. You just define it in one and -bam- it's available in others. However, passing instance variables between __requests__ is impossible (if that's what your two "methods" are - controller actions backing different requests)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If it's between requests, you can pass and iD and then retrieve it from the database

Comment: @GrahamSlick: if you have an id and if it is stored in database. And still the passing of id is not done via instance variables.

Comment: Both are different requests. `new_equipment_matches_wanted` is one system email with it's own template and `send_receivers_to_admin` is another system email with another template. I had to write the same lines in the second method too just to fetch the values in `@receiver`. And `@receiver` is not in db.

Comment: then you should use before_method,as I explained in my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instance variables ( with @) are shared among all the controller's methods.

```
def new_equipment_matches_wanted
 #..........Big chucnk of code of about 7 to 8 lines and then..
 @receiver
end 
def send_receivers_to_admin
 @receiver.do_something
end
```

You can read more about variables [here](http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com.uy/2010/03/variables.html)

However, as Sergio said,

> "passing instance variables between requests is impossible...
>   controller actions backing different requests"

then you'll have to load @receiver on both methods, you can use [before_action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

```
class CustomController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :load_receiver, only [:send_receivers_to_admin,:new_equipment_matches_wanted]

def new_equipment_matches_wanted
  @receiver.do_something
end 

def send_receivers_to_admin
 @receiver.do_something
end 

private

def load_receiver
    # Big chucnk of code of about 7 to 8 lines and then..
    @receiver
end
```

Comment: I read in the Action Mailer documentation that it supports `before_action`  `after_action`  and  `around_action`. So I can use it then right?

Answer (score 0):

I created a class variable instead and accessing that variable from any class necessary.

A class variable is written as @@variable_name inside a class (or controller) before declaring any method